# Free a pointer from an external function

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I wrote a program that uses a stack ADT.
The main creates a new stack while giving 3 functions to use from the user:

```
Stack my_stack = sCreate (copy_int, free_int, print_int);
```

when I call to a 'peek' function:

```
printf ("Peek: |%d|\n\n", *(int*)sPeek(my_stack));
```

**I have a memory leak.**

the peek function looks like this:

```
Element sPeek (Stack stack){
if ((NULL == stack) || (0 >= stack->used_places))
    return NULL;

Element returnElement = stack->copy_function(stack->stack_array[stack->used_places-1]);
if (NULL == returnElement){
    free (returnElement);
    return NULL;
}   
return returnElement;
```

It's caused probably by the copy_function called there, which is the copy_int that was given by the user:

```
Element copy_int (Element element){
int *new_int = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int*));
*new_int = *(int*)element;
if (NULL != new_int)
    return new_int;
else
    return NULL;
```

How do I release the pointer (malloc) from copy_int?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but do you really think that allocating space for one int pointer (`malloc(sizeof(int*))`) is a good idea ?

Comment: Are you suggesting to do the same thing on the stack? I mean without malloc?

Comment: Whenever possible you should try not to use using `malloc`, in this case, you don't need `malloc` at all, you could simply return the `int` without using malloc : `return *(int*)element;`

Comment: Your peek primitive shouldn't copy anything. Peek means look. You don't copy things you want to look at. Push should copy, pop should free. Alternatively, if you do want to make a copy to look at, it becomes the user's responsibility to clean it up after use.

Comment: Also tell your user that their `copy_int` is wrong. Count your stars: `Type <n stars> name = malloc(nelems * sizeof(Type <n-1 stars>))`. Easy! And don't cast the rwturn value of malloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last code snippet, you're using `*new_int` before checking the return value from `malloc`. That's going to cause a segmentation fault if `new_int` is `NULL`. Furthermore, the `if/else` is completely worthless as written. Those four lines could be replaced with `return new_int;` with absolutely no change in behavior under any circumstances. Finally, [don't cast the return value from malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

With all of those problems fixed, the last code snippet looks like this

```
Element copy_int (Element element)
{
    int *new_int = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if ( new_int )
        *new_int = *(int*)element;
    return new_int;
}
```

In the `sPeek` function, you have a similar worthless `if` statement. If the `returnElement` is `NULL`, there's nothing to `free`. So the `sPeek` function should be

```
Element sPeek (Stack stack)
{
    if ( stack && stack->used_places > 0 )
        return stack->copy_function(stack->stack_array[stack->used_places-1]);
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Finally to your question, the memory returned by `copy_int` *will* be leaked unless you keep a copy of that pointer, and `free` it when you're done with it. Also, you're asking for another segmentation fault if you pass a NULL pointer to `printf`. So the `printf` line needs to be replaced with this code (assuming that `Element` is really `void *`)

```
int *value = sPeek(my_stack);
if (value)
    printf ("Peek: |%d|\n\n", *value);
free(value);
```

Comment: Your answer "fixed" my problem. I used the 2 fixes and it works great with less code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Element e = sPeek(my_stack);
if (e) {
    printf ("Peek: |%d|\n\n", *(int*)e);
}
free(e);
```

Seems a bit obvious so not sure if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I release the pointer (malloc) from copy_int?

Just call `free()` on it, if you do not need it any more.

---

Also here

```
int * new_int = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int*));
*new_int = *(int*)element;
if (NULL != new_int)
  return new_int;
else
  return NULL;
```

the test for `NULL` should be done before de-referencing the pointer `element`:

```
int *new_int = malloc(sizeof(int*));
if (NULL != new_int)
{
  *new_int = *(int*)element;
  return new_int;
}
else
  return NULL;
```

Note: Casting the result of `malloc/calloc/realloc` is not necessary in C nor is it recommended in any way.

---

Also^2 the call to `free()` here:

```
if (NULL == returnElement){
  free (returnElement);
  return NULL;
}
```

is use less, as there is nothing to `free()`, as `returnElement` point nowhere b carrying `NULL`. You want to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Any function that returns a resource that is not automatically released after use must have documentation how to release the resource. In the case of `malloc()`, it's documented as `free()`, for `fopen()` it's `fclose()` etc.

When you create a function yourself, you can e.g. refer to `free()`, if you return a pointer that you in turn received from `malloc()`. If you have a more complex setup, you might have to create your own function.

Looking at your function, you alloc memory using `malloc()`, then assign to the memory (or blow up if the allocation fails, which you verify too late), then return exactly the pointer received from `malloc()`. Therefore, you are returning a resource that can (and must!) be released with `free()`.

BTW: Consider not copying things unnecessarily. Your call of `copy_int()` seems superfluous to me, just return a pointer to const int, referencing the existing element, and you should be fine.